# Creating android Lockscreen widgets/notification for an app

Tags: android, lockscreen

I've seen many apps do this.  Lux comes to mind, also the music player app, and other apps.  They display a notification on the lockscreen that has functionality you can interact with.  I read lockscreen widgets have been removed on 5.0+, but I still see these apps creating these lockscreen functionality.

I am new to Android development so maybe I am confused on the terminology.  Where can I find info on how to create this type of lockscreen functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI It can be done using [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) part of Android since ICS
This part of the code is to intercept media controls.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public void setUpRemoteControlClient() {
Context context = VLCApplication.getAppContext();
AudioManager audioManager = AudioManager)context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(Util.isICSOrLater()) {    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mRemoteControlClientReceiverComponent);
    if (mRemoteControlClient == null) {
        Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
      mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(mRemoteControlClientReceiverComponent);
        PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
        // create and register the remote control client
        mRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
        audioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(mRemoteControlClient);
    }
    mRemoteControlClient.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT |
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP);
} else if (Util.isFroyoOrLater()) {
    audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mRemoteControlClientReceiverComponent);
}
```

}

Comment: Perfect, this is a great starting point.  Just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanxx @ Marcelo Mason